# Does polymorphism interfere with NHibernate's batch insert/update capabilities?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, polymorphism, batching

I have a class structure like so:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected internal set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : Person
{
    public virtual string AccountNumber { get; set; }
}
```

`Customer` is mapped as a subclass of `Person` (using FluentNHibernate's `SubclassMap<T>`), and the table structure is table-per-subclass (separate `Person` and `Customer` tables sharing an `Id` column).

In my test, I open a stateless session and try to insert a series of `Person` entities:

```
using (var stateless = sessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession())
using (var transaction = stateless.BeginTransaction())
{
    var persons = new[]
    {
        new Person { Name = "Alice" },
        new Person { Name = "Bob" },
        new Customer { Name = "Cathy", AccountNumber = "001" },
        new Customer { Name = "Dave", AccountNumber = "002" }
    };
    foreach (var person in persons)
        stateless.Insert(person);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

If I run this with the `ShowSql` switch on, I can see that there are **no** `INSERT` statements generated on the `Person` table (meaning that they are batched), but there **are** individual `INSERT` statements being generated for the `Customer` table (from which I infer that these are *not* being batched).

Oddly enough, I've found that if the derived type (i.e. `Customer`) has its own collection (let's call them `Orders`) and I `Insert` each item in that collection directly into the same stateless session (not into the actual collection), it batches those too and has no trouble resolving the relationships. This behaviour seems to be entirely limited to derived classes of polymorphic entities.

Is this expected behaviour? If so, is there any way that I can rewrite the insertion code above to ensure that all of the subclass tables are batched as well?

(Note: I am using the `SequenceHiLoGenerator` for all IDs, and I've configured the `AdoNetBatchSize` accordingly, so this is *not* a general issue with batching, as far as I can tell. I can see the `HiLo` table being hit when a batch operation would be occurring.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several days of digging and experimentation, the answer seems to be "yes". There are various [scattered blog posts](http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/a-few-ideas-to-improve-nhibernate-performance/) mentioning in passing that NHibernate has trouble batching subclasses - specifically when using the **table per subclass** strategy (which I've been using).

It's not an issue with the table-per-class-hierarchy strategy. Unfortunately, it was way too late in the game for me to be changing the persistence model (plus, I really dislike TPH from a relational DB design perspective), so I had to look at other options.

I was able to work around the issue in the following way for inserts:

1. Make the base class concrete (it used to be abstract);
2. Make a shallow copy of each object to be inserted (constructing only the base class);
3. Insert the copies as usual;
4. Flush the session to meet referential integrity constraints;
5. Use  `SqlBulkCopy` to insert the derived classes into their own tables, using some scary voodoo based on casting the `IClassMetadata` to `AbstractEntityPersister` in order to get all of the column/table mappings;
6. Insert any mapped collections owned by subclasses using the `IStatelessSession.Insert` method as normal (repeat this process for collections with their own class hierarchies).

Updates, I imagine, would be a lot more complicated, and probably very difficult to handle without relying on hard-coded table/column names; if I had to do this, I would probably rely on Stored Procedures (with Table-Valued Parameters, or staging tables) instead.

The resulting code is not pleasant to look at, but it makes for a significant performance improvement - at least 25% for normal-sized batches of about 20-30k.

Comment: This one is biting us hard right now.  We have a scenario where table-per-subclass works quite nicely but would be a mess with table-per-class-hierarchy (plus we are late game as well).  One of our initial approaches was going to be to do these updates out of process with some manual SQL, but we're also experiencing challenges expiring our 2nd level cache to make sure NH knows it's data is stale for this object hierarchy.  So frustrating. We're on 3.3.4.4000.  Not sure if this is a problem in 4.x, but I haven't read anything to suggest otherwise.